# Verifying the type of an AggregateException's inner exception in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception-handling, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I've got the following code inside an integration test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Integration_GetUser_WithoutLoggingIn_ThrowsInvalidOperationException()
{
    var myApi = new Api(new Session());

    try
    {
        var irrelevant = myApi.GetUserInfoAsync().AsTask().Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        if (ae.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(InvalidOperationException))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.Fail("There was no InvalidOperationException.");
        }
    }
}
```

Some remarks about it:

- I am writing a Windows Runtime Component so the return type *has* to be `IAsyncOperation<T>`, `Task<T>` is not an option.
- I am blocking the call using `AsTask().Result`, is this the most appropriate method?
- Exceptions thrown in an asynchronous chain return [`AggregateException`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#2129) so I want to inspect that it throws the exception which I defined as "you are not logged in".
- I'm using MSTest because NUnit can't handle WinRT types (which stinks in combination with integration tests).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am blocking the call using `AsTask().Result`, is this the most appropriate method?

Can't you use `await`? Most testing frameworks ([apparently including MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10736873/41071)) support `async` tests. That way, you could work directly with the inner exception instead of the `AggregateException`.

---

```
if (ae.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(InvalidOperationException))
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
else
{
    Assert.Fail("There was no InvalidOperationException.");
}
```

I think this should be shortened to just:

```
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ae.InnerException.GetType());
```

Or maybe:

```
Assert.AreEqual(
    typeof(InvalidOperationException), ae.InnerException.GetType(),
    "There was no InvalidOperationException.");
```

---

> Exceptions thrown in an asynchronous chain return `AggregateException` so I want to inspect that it throws the exception which I defined as "you are not logged in".

But you're not doing that, you're just checking that it's `InvalidOperationException`. If you want to test for this, maybe you should use a custom exception type?

Comment: I recall having some very annoying MSTest issues when marked `async` (randomly chosen tests wouldn't get detected), but I'll take another look at it. You're right, I don't know why I made my assert so incredibly complicated. I'll change that. As to the custom exception type: I would have, but I can't. WinRT does not allow me to expose them.

Answer (score 2):

The test will still be passed if there is not any exception thrown by below code which seems not you desires

```
var irrelevant = myApi.GetUserInfoAsync().AsTask().Result;
```

So maybe need change the code a little bit as below

```
try
{
   var irrelevant = myApi.GetUserInfoAsync().AsTask().Result;
   Assert.Fails("Should throw exception before here.");
}
catch ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One small observation: the test will not fail if no exception is thrown.  This isn't one of my languages, but I'd expect something like

```
try {
    callFunction();
    Assert.Fails("Should have thrown exception")
} catch (…)
   ⋮
```